# How to create a Excel formula that finds the corresponding range in a matrix for a given value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to create a Microsoft Excel formula which finds the corresponding range in a matrix for a given value.

### Explained with a generic example

#### Reference table

```
| Name | From | To |
| A    |    1 |  5 |
| B    |    6 |  8 |
| C    |    9 |  9 |
```

#### Source table

```
| Name | Value |
|      |     0 |
|      |     4 |
|      |     9 |
  ^
  Field is getting "calculated".
```

#### Result table

```
| Name | Value |
|      |     0 |
| A    |     4 |
| B    |     6 |
| C    |     9 |
  ^
  Field is getting "calculated".
```

### Specific explanation

In my reference table I do have frequencies with information in which band the frequency range is and how many Watts I am allowed to use.

In my source/result table (the same) I have a frequency list and would like to have the band and Watts information automatically assigned to it.

#### Reference table

```
|  Band | Frequency Range | Watts |
| 160 m |  1.810 |  1.850 |   100 |
| 160 m |  1.890 |  2.000 |    10 |
```

#### Expected result table

```
             First part is source field for the look up.
             v
|  Band | Frequency Range | Watts | Description |
| 160 m |  1.811 |  1.811 |   100 | Foo Bar     |
| 160 m |  1.891 |  1.897 |    10 | Lorem ipsum |
    ^                         ^
    Field is "calculated".    Field is "calculated".
```

### Conclusion

How to define (when it is possible at all due to the range) a Excel formula which picks the correct matrix reference row from a matrix while looking up a single value within a range from the matrix?

The formula should be compatible with Excel 97 but at very least with Excel 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to use `VLOOKUP` to get this information.

At first copy / move your "from" column to be the leftmost one, so your columns will be organized: A (from), B (name), C (to).

If you have continuous range (e.g. you can consider 1.870 in your example as member of first group) then your formula (in A2 of your results table): `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,reference_sheet!A:C,2,true),"")`

If you want to get empty values when your frequency is between ranges, than your formula will be more complicated (still using references according to the generale example):

- first get the row of your group ignoring upper limit: `=IFERROR(MATCH(B2,reference_sheet!A:C,1),"")` - put this in e.g. column C
- then check whether your value is within the range: `=IFERROR(B2<=index(reference_sheet!C:C,C2),FALSE)`

You have now row number in column D and `TRUE` in column E for each of your entries, with the `INDEX` function now you can collect the data you need. (it's also possible to do everything without any helper column but formulae will be far more complex that case)

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to alter your reference table such that the range column is the leftmost column then the `VLOOKUP` function should do what you want. Because you're trying to match against ranges, rather than specific values, you should make sure your reference table is in range-sorted order and pass `TRUE` to `VLOOKUP` as the 4th parameter.

If you don't want to rearrange the reference table to position the ranges on the left then you can achieve similar results using a combination of `MATCH` and `INDEX` functions.

These functions are all available in Excel 2007 and later versions.